# Python fails to import when accessed from web server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tensorflow

Python does not import when accessed from web server

I am new to Python and Google App Engine, may that is why I can not figure out this simple problem.

I just started Google App Engine and completed Hello world thing. I started web server and I could see hello world in my browser. It worked fine.

Since I need tensorflow to develop my app, I imported it like the line 2 below.

```
import webapp2
import tensorflow

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Now it does not work and produce `ImportError: No module named tensorflow`. 
Tensorflow is in fact properly installed and the script works fine from my command line.

I wrote other scripts and they always properly import using command line but can not import when accessed from the web server.

My wild guess is that this is the permission issue of the web server process (since it is the one accessing to the python script in question) but I am not sure.

Please help.

**[UPDATE and Supplemental info 1]**

In the original post, I made the issue simple for ease of communication. Yet in fact I want to import 6 libraries like below.

```
import webapp2
import base64
import json
import tensorflow as tf
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
```

All of them are successfully imported when the script is run via command line of Cloud Shell.

However, when accessed from web server, first 3 libraries (i.e. webapp2, base64, joson) were successfully imported, but last 3 libraries (i.e. tensorflow, Googleapiclient, googel.oauth2) were not imported.

In Google App Engine, how can python script not import google libraries when access from web server process?

**[UPDATE and Supplemental info 2]**

I have not changed the folder and it is very simple.
In hello_world folder, there are four files, app.yaml, main.py, main.pyc, requirements.txt

I left the app.yaml un-tuched like below.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

I listed the libraries in requirements.txt like below and run `pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt` but it does not solve the problem.

```
webapp2==2.5.2
webob==1.8.0
google-api-python-client==1.6.5
google-auth==1.4.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
```

Comment: Please show us how you run the script and your webserver including the related configuration.

Comment: How are you including the `tensorflow` library into your project? Have you read & followed the directions over at [Using third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27)? Also, note that the libraries you are including must be in pure python without any C code (if `tensorflow` has no C code - you likely shouldn't have any issues unless it does extensive writing to local disk as well). If you are still having difficulties - show your `app.yaml`, `appengine_config.py` files and project's directory structure.

Comment: Klaus D and Mihail Russu, thank you for the comments. I run the script from command line of Cloud Shell. Related configuration is only app.yaml, which I have not changed and requirements.txt. I do not use appengine_config.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine Standard has application restrictions explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#standard_environment_languages_and_runtimes): The interpreter cannot load Python services with C code; it is a "pure" Python environment. Since TensorFlow has code in C, it cannot work unless you modify the Python interpreter (which is unsuggested).

Therefore TensorFlow is more suited for App Engine Flexible. Follow this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart) to obtain an equivalent code solution for the Flexible environment.

Before installing the virtual environment, modify `requirements.txt` to add the TensorFlow dependencies link as you can see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package) and continue with the installation in the *quickstart* [guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart).

The resulting test code for `main.py`:

```
# [START app]
import logging
import tensorflow as tf

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    #return 'Hello World!'
    return tf.Session().run(tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')) 

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return """
    An internal error occurred: <pre>{}</pre>
    See logs for full stacktrace.
    """.format(e), 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Google App Engine. See entrypoint in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
# [END app]
```

The resulting entries for `requirements.txt` are:

```
Flask==0.12.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.6.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: Thank you, Ruben C!! Yes, changing GAE service to Flexible made it successful. Thank you for the detailed explanation!!

Comment: Happy to hear that! Could you accept the answer, please? Thank you in advance.